# Faster way of passing through a matrix in R

Tags: r

I have a huge matrix variable mat with M rows and N columns. I need to find all the locations which are non-zeros. Currently I am writing the following code to do that

```
Rowindex_set = c() #Generate the set of all row indexes of all non-zero entries
Colindex_set = c() #Generate the set of all col indexes of all non-zero entries
for(i in 1:M){
  for(j in 1:N){
    if (mat[i,j] != 0){
      Rowindex_set = c(Rowindex_set,i)
      Colindex_set = c(Colindex_set,j)  
    }
  }
}
```

M and N are typically in the range of ten thousands. This piece of code takes lot of time because of that. Is there a faster way to do this?

EDIT: 
I did some modifications and came up with an even more faster implementation.

```
Rowindex_set = rep.int(0,M*N) #Large vector of zeros
Colindex_set = rep.int(0,M*N) #Large vector of zeros
IndexCounter = 1
for(i in 1:M){
  for(j in 1:N){
    if (incomp_mat[i,j] != marker){
      Rowindex_set[IndexCounter] = i #Update each entry, rather than appending as earlier
      Colindex_set[IndexCounter] = j #Similar as above comment
      IndexCounter = IndexCounter + 1
    }
  }
}
Rowindex_set = Rowindex_set[-IndexCounter:-(M*N)] # Remove trailing zeros
Colindex_set = Colindex_set[-IndexCounter:-(M*N)] # Remove trailing zeros
```

Thus instead of appending new entries to Rowindex_set and Colindex_set in each iteration, I initialize them to a larger sized vector of zeros, and then update each entry. In the end, I remove the remaining entries

Comment: Check argument `arr.ind` of the `which` function.

Comment: @Pascal please add this as an answer.

Comment: @dineshdileep -- It's totally fine/recommended that, in a situation like this, you post the answer yourself and then accept it (after a mandatory 2-day wait).  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

After that what you have to do? Based on that you can make it very fast. Need not write loop at all. For example if you have to substitute 0's with NA you can do this.

```
M <- matrix(c(1,2,3,0,0,2),nrow=2)
M[M==0] <- NA

## OR change all nonzero elements

M[M!=0] <- NA
```

So, mention what you have to do next and depends on that you can figure out a way to do that.

OR if it is just about getting indices try

```
apply(M,2,function(x) which(x!=0))
```

Which a list of nonzero indices column wise

Comment: As Pascal noted above, try instead `which(m!=0, arr.ind=TRUE)`

Comment: what I do after that is a really complicated algorithm. And as of now, that piece of code runs very much faster than this and am happy with its execution speed.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien If I use that, will I get row indices as well as column indices?

Comment: @dineshdileep - the great thing about R is that it is interactive. Try it and see! (Spoiler - yes).

Comment: yeah!! you are right. I apologize for the triviality :):)